# PowerPoint 2007 SP2, ExportAsFixedFormat in PowerShell?

Tags: pdf, com, powershell, powerpoint, office-2007

Yesterday I was trying to batch convert a group of PPTs into PDFs for a friend, and I decided to have a look at PowerShell, since it's been sitting on my HD for a while.

Here's the code I've come up with.

```
$p = new-object -comobject powerpoint.application

# I actually don't know why I have to set the window to visible, 
# but it doesn't work otherwise, anyway, it's not the real problem I have
$p.visible = 1 

$f = $p.presentations.open('\some\file.ppt')

$f.ExportAsFixedFormat('\some\newfile.pdf', 2)
```

[2 is for PDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb265637.aspx)

Since the "brute force" method didn't work ("type mismatch") I tried to import the enum type with

```
$pptypepdf= [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatType]::PpFixedFormatTypePDF
$f.ExportAsFixedFormat('\some\newfile.pdf', $pptypepdf)
```

The strange thing here is that it still throws a "type mismatch" error...

Also, SaveAs works fine with

```
$f.SaveAs('\some\newfile.pdf', 32) # 32 is for PDF
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Relevant documentation:

- [PpFixedFormatType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb265637.aspx)
- [ExportAsFixedFormat Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231096.aspx)

Here's the full error message

```
$pptypepdf= [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatType]::PpFixedFormatTypePDF
$f.ExportAsFixedFormat($filepath, $pptypepdf)

Exception calling "ExportAsFixedFormat" with "2" argument(s): "Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"

At line:1 char:23
+ $f.ExportAsFixedFormat <<<< ($filepath, $pptypepdf)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

Comment: What is the exact error?  I checked MSDN, and the documentation on this method seems to be wrong for this argument.  And I can't even find that enumeration on MSDN!

Comment: I've edited the question with the relevant details, thank you

Comment: Have you tried a call giving all optional parameters?

Comment: PowerPoint's ExportAsFixedFormat will return "Type Mismatch" when the "optional" parameters are missing.  Only if all of the parameters are provided is the puArgErr value returned by Invoke meaningful.

Comment: Hi NoWhereMan, did you find a solution to this problem in the meantime?

Comment: I settled on using plain SaveAs and I didn't bother further; if you want to play with this, feel free to report back here.

Comment: Please see the solution I've provided here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086541/powerpoint-exportasfixedformat-in-powershell/22835945#22835945) and see if that works!

Answer (score 2):

I've come across the same problem in Python. Try specifying `PrintRange` argument as said in solution by Stefan Schukat:

> This is a bug in Powerpoint. It defines "[in, optional,
>   defaultvalue(0)] PrintRange* PrintRange" which leads to the generation
>   of "PrintRange=0" in the python wrapper. Therefore you'll get the
>   error when calling the method. So no problem of makepy. Workaround
>   call the method with PrintRange=None since None is a vali COM object.
>   E.g. presentation.ExportAsFixedFormat(pptFile+'.pdf',
>   win32com.client.constants.ppFixedFormatTypePDF,
>   win32com.client.constants.ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, PrintRange=None)
>   should work.

[Source: Type mismatch when using export fuction of PowerPoint 2007](http://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/339/)

---

I don't know PowerShell at all but have worked out a working example:

```
$p.ActivePresentation.PrintOptions.Ranges.Add(1,1)
$r = $p.ActivePresentation.PrintOptions.Ranges.Item(1)
$document.ExportAsFixedFormat('D:\\ps.pdf', 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, $r)
```

This isn't a full solution, but exporting is done. It somehow exports full presentation, not only slide no. 1, as I thought. P.S. Oh. Here's the same [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22835945/1119602)