# PowerPoint ExportAsFixedFormat in Powershell

Tags: pdf, powershell, export, powerpoint

I try to use the `ExportAsFixedFormat` in PowerPoint 2007 from a PowerShell 2.0 script. Only the first two arguments are required, but that won't work.

I always get:

> Exception calling "ExportAsFixedFormat" with "2"
>   argument(s): "Type mismatch. (
>   Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"

I've read that all arguments have to be specified for it to function, but that doesn't work either. BTW, the same method works for me in Word 2007 and Excel 2007.

So what is wrong with this:

```
Add-type -AssemblyName Office
Add-type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

$p = new-object -comobject powerpoint.application 
$p.visible = 1  
$document = $p.presentations.open('somefile.ppt')


$document.ExportAsFixedFormat($Path, 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatType]::ppFixedFormatTypePDF, 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatIntent]::ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, 
[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse, 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintHandoutOrder]::ppPrintHandoutVerticalFirst, 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintOutputType]::ppPrintOutputSlides, 
[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse, 
$null, 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintRangeType]::ppPrintAll, 
[System.Reflection.Missing]::Value, 
$true, 
$true, 
$true, 
$true, 
$false, 
[System.Reflection.Missing]::Value)
```

Answer (score 4):

I realise this is a late answer, but I think I've got the solution. (I was trying to call this method in c# using NetOffice, and getting the same error)

It appears that there is a bug in Microsoft Powerpoint (At least in v 2007 & 2010). 
The PrintRange parameter must be specified, because the default (0) is invalid!

So a working script might look like:

```
Add-type -AssemblyName Office
Add-type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

$p = new-object -comobject powerpoint.application 
$p.visible = 1  
$document = $p.presentations.open('somefile.ppt')
$ranges = $document.PrintOptions.Ranges
$range = $ranges.Add(1,1)


$document.ExportAsFixedFormat($Path, 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatType]::ppFixedFormatTypePDF, 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatIntent]::ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, 
[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse, 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintHandoutOrder]::ppPrintHandoutVerticalFirst, 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintOutputType]::ppPrintOutputSlides, 
[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse, 
$range, 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintRangeType]::ppPrintAll, 
[System.Reflection.Missing]::Value, 
$true, 
$true, 
$true, 
$true, 
$false, 
[System.Reflection.Missing]::Value)
```

notice the $range parameter is now passed in.

NB - this answer is adapted from the solution here: https://netoffice.codeplex.com/discussions/449288

Comment: Interesting - but shouldn't that bug manifest itself also when ppt is called with another language? Its COM, after all, there should be nothing special about calling it from Powershell.
Thats said, I've switched to VB.NET since, because its much better suited to do interop with MS Office. There are features where you have to call stuff in Office VB, which is dynamic and thus is much harder todo with other .NET languages.

Comment: I don't think there is anything special about calling it from powershell - as I said I came accross this problem in a c# program using NetOffice (which is a nice alternative to the office interop assemblies), so I assume the problem is universal

Comment: I can confirm this solution for Office 2010. For 2016, use [Robert's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74059554/11942268) (which includes a *proper* range).

Answer (score 2):

There were two issues with the parameters:

1. use a proper **PrintRange**
2. for **ExternalExporter**, `[System.Reflection.Missing]::Value` is invalid. Just skip it.

```
Add-type -AssemblyName Office
Add-type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

$ppt = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application
$presentation = $ppt.Presentations.Open($inputPath)
$printRange = $presentation.PrintOptions.Ranges.Add(1, $presentation.Slides.Count)

$presentation.ExportAsFixedFormat2(
    $outputPath, 
    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatType]::ppFixedFormatTypePDF, # FixedFormatType
    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpFixedFormatIntent]::ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, # Intent
    [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue, # FrameSlides
    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintHandoutOrder]::ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFirstl, # HandoutOrder (ppPrintHandoutVerticalFirst)
    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintOutputType]::ppPrintOutputSlides, # OutputType (ppPrintOutputBuildSlides)
    [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoFalse, # PrintHiddenSlides
    $printRange, # PrintRange <-- use a proper printRange
    [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpPrintRangeType]::ppPrintAll, # RangeType
    [System.Reflection.Missing]::Value, # SlideShowName
    $false, # IncludeDocProperties
    $false, # KeepIRMSettings
    $false, # DocStructureTags
    $false, # BitmapMissingFonts
    $false, # PDF/A UseISO19005_1
    $true # includeMarkup 
    # ExternalExporter <-- skip this param completely
    )

$presentation.Close()
$ppt.Quit()

[System.GC]::Collect();
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers();
[System.GC]::Collect();
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Code is from very complete example at https://gist.github.com/allenyllee/5d7c4a16ae0e33375e4a6d25acaeeda2

Answer (score 0):

Change `$null` to `[System.Reflection.Missing]::Value`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, no success.