# Exporting PPT presentation to PDF from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am trying to export PPT presentation to PDF format from Excel VBA. In code below, I constantly receive Type Mismatch error when attepmting to use ExportAsFixedFormat. Why? Please see the code below

```
Option Explicit
Private Const ppSaveAsPDF As Long = 2
Private Const ppSaveAsDefault As Long = 11
Private Const ppSaveAsPresentation As Long = 1

Private Const ppFixedFormatTypePDF As Long = 2
Private Const ppFixedFormatIntentPrint As Long = 2
Private Const msoTrue As Long = -1
Private Const ppPrintHandoutHorizontalFirst As Long = 2
Private Const ppPrintOutputType As Long = 2
Private Const ppPrintOutputFourSlideHandouts As Long = 8
Private Const ppPrintOutputTwoSlideHandouts As Long = 2
Sub My_PowerPointToPDF()

Dim oPowerPointApp As Object
Dim oPPT As Object
Dim sPowerPointSourceFileName As String
Dim sPowerPointDestFileName As String

sPowerPointSourceFileName = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\PPTX 2 PDF Button.pptm"
sPowerPointDestFileName = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\test.pdf"

On Error Resume Next       'Will error on GetObject if not already open
Set oPowerPointApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If oPowerPointApp Is Nothing Then   'If Nothing then GetObject failed because PowerPoint not already open.
    Set oPowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
End If

oPowerPointApp.Visible = True
Set oPPT = oPowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(sPowerPointSourceFileName)

'Line below creates "Type mismatch" error. Why?
oPPT.ExportAsFixedFormat Path:=sPowerPointDestFileName, FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF

oPPT.Close
oPowerPointApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't want to manually add reference to Microsoft PowerPoint library in Excel VBA as the file with macro will be mailed to many persons.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug or error in the PowerPoint documentation for `ExportAsFixedFormat`. `PrintRange` is not optional. You can fix the error by adding a parameter of `PrintRange:=Nothing`.

I had the same issue and this answer clued me in to the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32995017/3541707